# Как сделать поля класса скрытыми?

Tags: c++

Как сделать поля класса скрытыми абсолютно для всех?

Comment: private? или даже для самого класса тоже скрытными?

Comment: кроме самого себя еще есть друзья, которые тоже видят поля.

Comment: А смысл использования таки "супер скрытых" полей? Зачем они вообще будут нужны, если к ним нельзя будет обратиться даже из методов класса?

Comment: private???

Comment: @Илья Михневич, я, конечно же не про поля с уровнем инкапсуляции **private**! Я про тот неизведанный уровень закрытости, который нужен ТС.

Answer (score 2):

Директива private, скажем так, самая "скрытная". Поля и методы в ней доступны только классу, в котором они описаны. А так от остальных скрыты.
"Скрытнее" директивы нет.

Comment: Еще "скрытнее" может оказаться использование идеологии [`PIMPL`][1]. Хотя, конечно, вопрос требует определения четкого критерия желаемой "скрытности".

[1]: http://insidecpp.ru/patterns/pimpl_idiom/

Comment: PIMPL похож на паттерн "Чеширский кот"

Answer (score 0):

вроде можно описать переменные используемые в методах как static и тогда сам хрен до них доберешься из соседнего метода даже